# Rust returns a result error from fn: mismatched types

Tags: rust, rust-result

I want this function to return an error result:

```
fn get_result() -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
     // Ok(String::from("foo")) <- works fine
     Result::Err(String::from("foo"))
}
```

Error Message

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:3:17
  |
3 |     Result::Err(String::from("foo"))
  |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::io::Error`, found struct `std::string::String`
  |
  = note: expected type `std::io::Error`
             found type `std::string::String`
```

I'm confused how I can print out an error message when using the expected struct.

Comment: You'll need to clarify this question. Nothing in here involves printing. A Result is just a normal datatype. Is the question how make Rust print an error based on the return type of `get_result`, or is it more about how to fix the type error? Currently you just have mismatched types and it isn't clear why you want to use `std::io::Error` to begin with if you have a string error.

Comment: The compiler and the code are clear. You must put a `std::io::Error` and you put a `String`. What is your question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error message is quite clear. Your return type for `get_result` is `Result<String, std::io::Error>`, meaning that in the `Result::Ok` case, the inner value of the `Ok` variant is of type `String`, whereas in the `Result::Err` case, the inner value of the `Err` variant is of type `std::io::Error`.

Your code attempted to create an `Err` variant with an inner value of type `String`, and the compiler rightfully complains about a type mismatch. To create a new `std::io::Error`, you can use the [`new` method on `std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.new). Here's an example of your code using the correct types:

```
fn get_result() -> Result<String, std::io::Error> {
    Err(std::io::Error::new(std::io::ErrorKind::Other, "foo"))
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You might want to do something like this, if I get it right...

```
fn get_result() -> Result<String, String> {
   // Ok(String::from("foo")) <- works fine
   Result::Err(String::from("Error"))
}

fn main(){
    match get_result(){
        Ok(s) => println!("{}",s),
        Err(s) => println!("{}",s)
    };
}
```

I wouldn't recommend doing this though.